# What do we mean by this line regarding C language's I/O?

Tags: c, io

This is a little subjective question I can't understand after much of googling. I was going through a book and couldn't get the lines-
"Unlike other languages,C does not contain any instruction to display output on screen.All output to screen is achieved using readymade library functions." [Y Kanetkar, Let Us C].
What does it mean? In C we can output using printf(), While in Java we can output using print()/println().
So how's C different?? As far as I can get, C does everything in files, uses stdin and stdout for standard input and output. But then how are other languages different?? They must be controlling devices in the same manner too??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java, which is to some extent styled after C++ , is a bad example here. Some other languages, like Pascal, Python, BASIC, etc. do have built-in statements for I/O, and these are the languages the author is comparing C to. Some languages, like C, require you to call a function to do output, while other languages have I/O built in. Don't read too much into the sentence; nothing profound is going on here.